# How to measure and display the running time of a single test?

Tags: scala, duration, measurement, scalatest

I have a potentially long-running test written with *scalatest*:

```
test("a long running test") {
  failAfter(Span(60, Seconds)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Even if the test finishes within the timeout limit, its running time can be valuable to the person who runs the test. How can I measure and display the running time of this *single* particular test in scalatest's output?

**Update:** Currently I measure the running time with my own function, just as in r.v's answer. I'd like to know if *scalatest* offers this functionality already.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the `-oD` option will give the duration of the test. For example, I use the following in my build.sbt.

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oD")
```

EDIT:

You can also use the following for individual runs:

```
> test-only org.acme.RedSuite -- -oD
```

See http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt.

Moreover, you can define the following function for general time measurements:

```
def time[T](str: String)(thunk: => T): T = {
  print(str + "... ")
  val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
  val x = thunk
  val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
  println((t2 - t1) + " msecs")
  x
}
```

and use it anywhere (not dependent on ScalaTest)

```
test("a long running test") {
  time("test running"){
    failAfter(Span(60, Seconds)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but I'd like to measure only a single test and regardless of sbt's configuration. I don't need to measure the other tests and I'd like to always measure this one. I was thinking about measuring a block of code and printing its time at the end of the test using `info(...)`. I was hoping that  _scalatest_ offers such a measurement function, as it already performs measurements with this option.

Comment: I have edited the question. I don't know about `info()` but think my answer is equivalent and workable. Where is `info()` and what does it do?

Comment: Yes, that's how am I doing it now, with my own function like `time`. (Perhaps [`nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) could be a bit more precise.) | `info()` just adds a message to _scalatest_'s output.

Comment: In more recent versions of sbt and ScalaTest, we should set the test framework:  
```testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oD")```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to r.v.'s answer:
If you have multiproject builds the `testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oD")` does not work on root level in build.sbt, because Test refers to src/test/scala. You have to put it inside your Sub-Project settings

```
Project(id = "da_project", base = file("da_project"))
    .settings(
        testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oDG"),
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
            ...
        )
    )
```

Comment: Alternatively, we can set it at the whole build level:
```testOptions in Test in ThisBuild += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oD")```