# How to measure test running time using scalatest in Eclipse (Scala IDE)?

Tags: eclipse, performance, scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I found this post [How to measure and display the running time of a single test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436593/how-to-measure-and-display-the-running-time-of-a-single-test)

But it concerns about sbt approach rather than Eclipse approach.

Comment: The last approach ("_Moreover..._") described in the answer isn't dependent on sbt or even scalatest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `-Od` option (or any other) in an Eclipse invocation of a "main", see the scaladoc for [Runner](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/#org.scalatest.tools.Runner$).

The last approach ("*Moreover...*") described in the answer you referenced isn't dependent on sbt or even scalatest.